# How to check if type is a record

Tags: c#

Is it possible to check a type is a record?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IsRecord(typeof(Person)); // true
    }

    static bool IsRecord(Type type)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public record Person
{
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }

    public Person(string first, string last) => (FirstName, LastName) = (first, last);
}
```

Comment: Yes : type == typeof(Person)

Comment: Do you mean 
`Type.IsValueType`?

Comment: @jdweng having type == typeof(Person) cannot check the actual semantic of Person type. the OP wants to know how the determine if a type is a C# 9 _record_ or just a class.

Comment: @JoelFan [C# 9 records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records) are reference types.

Answer (score 11):

This is just based on a quick look at the compiled code with C# 9. There may be a more official way of determining this. But with what I'm seeing, record types define a public method named `<Clone>$` which is otherwise not a valid C# identifier, so if a type has that method the type is a record, barring some other tool able to rewrite the IL using that same name.

```
var t = typeof(Person);
var isRecord = t.GetMethods().Any(m => m.Name == "<Clone>$");
```

Comment: I was just about to write this answer... It's the best there is currently, given that all relevant `Type` properties have the same values as a class' type would

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting at least a custom attribute, since the C# compiler has to know which types were records, right? I haven't been keeping up on the C# 9 stuff too much, so maybe I'm wrong there.

Comment: Seems like syntactic sugar resolved by Roslyn, given that the code still needs to comply with IL and this is strictly a c# feature

Comment: And why compiler needs to know which types are records? It already compiled them, so seems no reason for it to care after that. Not sure why developer should care about that at runtime either... For example we usually don't bother whether some method is anonymous or not and how to check that.

Comment: Are there no constructs in C# 9 where one assembly could declare a record type T, and then another assembly that references the first need to know whether T (which is already compiled) is a record? Like I said, I haven't looked into it too deeply but it sounded like from the release notes that the `with` expression only works with record types.

Comment: Indeed, it seems kind of a "duck typing" is used, because with statement uses precisely Clone method described in your answer. So if such method is present, then it's good enough to be treated as record.

Comment: Starting from C# 10, the 'With' expression works with all Value Types and Anonymous objects as well, although they don't have the "<Clone>$" method because they are not records, so this solution is still viable

Comment: @JoeSewell this won't work with record structs introduced in C# 10. the `with` expression is implemented differently in structs and it doesn't require a `"<clone>$"` method